# How to extract query string parameters from URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a URL

> https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Generator+Repair&geo_location_terms=Adamsville%2C+Alabama

I want to get `search_terms` (Generator+Repair) and `geo_location_terms` (Adamsville%2C+Alabama)

How I can do this?

Comment: You can use regex to do that. Or use a URL parser library.Don't have name but you can search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most idiomatic way to do this in JavaScript is using the `URL` class:

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Generator+Repair&geo_location_terms=Adamsville%2C+Alabama')

console.log(url.searchParams.get('search_terms'));
console.log(url.searchParams.get('geo_location_terms'));
```

MDN reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Javascript code to store the GET parameters into an object:

```
<script>
    var URL = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Generator+Repair&geo_location_terms=Adamsville%2C+Alabama";

    var result = {};
    URL.substring(URL.indexOf("?") + 1).split('&').forEach(function(x){
        var arr = x.split('=');
        arr[1] && (result[arr[0]] = arr[1]);
    });

    console.log(result.search_terms);
    //OUTPUT: "Generator+Repair"
    console.log(result.geo_location_terms);
    //OUTPUT: "Adamsville%2C+Alabama"

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to get the 2 values:

```
/search_terms=(.*)&geo_location_terms=(.*)/
```

This is a very basic regex, that starts by matching '`search_terms=`' then creates a `Group` that matches any number of `any char` up to the `'&'` sign, then matches '`geo_location_terms='` and finally creates a Group that matches any number of `any char`.

Your desired output will be in `Group 1` and `Group 2`.

**How to use:**

```
var url = 'https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Generator+Repair&geo_location_terms=Adamsville%2C+Alabama';
var regex = /search_terms=(.*)&geo_location_terms=(.*)/;
var match = url.match(regex);

var search_terms = match[1];
var geo_location_terms = match[2];
```